# Add element on click and delete same element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dynamically-generated

I have this code which adds markers on a jpg map dynamically based on where you click on the map image. It creates the ids dynamically as well. I am trying to attach a click event to every dynamically created marker so that if the user clicks on the marker it will be deleted. The problem is that when they click on the marker it generates another marker. I want the user to be able to place the marker on the map by clicking on the map and then if they want to delete the marker they can click on it again without generating a new marker when they click on the marker they want to delete.

Thank you in advance for all your help.

**JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var clicks = 0;
    $("#container").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var x = e.pageX - 38;
        var y = e.pageY - 60;
        var img = $('<img>');
        img.css('top', y);
        img.css('left', x);
        img.css('width',60);
        img.css('height',60);
        img.attr('src', 'images/location-marker1.png');
        img.attr('id', 'marker' + clicks);
        img.attr('class', 'marker' + clicks);
        img.appendTo('#container');

        $("#container").on("click", "img.marker" + clicks, function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            alert(id);
            $(this).remove();
        });
        clicks += 1;
    })
});
```

**HTML :**

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="images/floorplan1_fs.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Ooooh, nesting event handlers in another are generally a bad idea.

Comment: do you want jquery, that would be easier

Comment: Your click event will propagate up from the `img` to the container. Try adding an event argument to your `img` click handler and calling `event.stopPropagation()` ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: Sorry I didn't get a chance to look at this until this morning. Thanks Terry I am a bit of a beginner when it comes to Javascript. Yes I know a little JQuery as well. I will try your suggestion George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, all you need to do is to (1) use a common class, say `marker`, to identify inserted markers, and (2) move the event listener out of the outer `click` function, and let it stand on its own right:

```
$("#container").on("click", "img.marker", function(e) {
    $(this).remove();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This not only greatly simplifies your script, as `#container` will now listen to click events emitted by all dynamically added `img.marker` elements, but the use of `e.stopPropagation` stops the click event from bubbling up to the parent, which causes a new child to be added when you click to remove one.

Here is a proof-of-concept example, with some minor changes to your base code:

1. There is no longer any need to track unique IDs
2. Here we take advantage of the amazing chaining capabilities imparted by jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#container").click(function(e) {
    
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var x = e.pageX - 38,
        y = e.pageY - 60,
        $img = $('<img>');
    
    $img
      .css({
        top: y,
        left: x,
        width: 60,
        height: 60
      })
      .attr({
        src: 'https://placehold.it/60x60'
      })
      .addClass('marker')
      .appendTo('#container');
  });

  $("#container").on("click", "img.marker", function(e) {
    $(this).remove();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
}
#container .marker {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/500x500">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a general class to attach the event and put it outside of the other click event :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var clicks = 0;
    $("#container").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var x = e.pageX - 38;
        var y = e.pageY - 60;
        var img = $('<img>');
        img.css('top', y);
        img.css('left', x);
        img.css('width',60);
        img.css('height',60);
        img.attr('src', 'images/location-marker1.png');
        img.attr('id', 'marker' + clicks);
        img.attr('class', 'marker');
        img.appendTo('#container');

        clicks += 1;
    })
    $("#container").on("click", "img.marker", function(){
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      alert(id);
      $(this).remove();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

**NOTE :** If you want to improve the code you could use :

```
$('<img />', {  
    'class' : "marker",
    src     : 'images/location-marker1.png',
    css     : {
        top    : y,  
        left   : x, 
        width  : 60, 
        height : 60, 
    },
    on : {
        click: function() {
             $(this).remove();
        }
    }
}).appendTo('#container');
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#container").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('<img />', {  
      'class' : 'marker',
      src     : 'https://www.gobages.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/marker-reservoirs.png',
      css     : {
        top    : e.pageY - 37,  
        left   : e.pageX - 24, 
        width  : 30, 
        height : 30, 
      },
      on : {
        click: function(e) {
          e.stopPropagation();
          $(this).remove();
        }
      }
    }).appendTo('#container');
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
}
#container .marker {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://geology.com/world/world-map-clickable.gif">
</div>
```